# Getting error in `undici` module `Class extends value #<child> is not a constructor or null` on node upgrade to 18.18.2 and above

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, undici, gaxios

I'm encountering a TypeError when making requests for a token from the `googleapis` library using a JWT client. The error message is as follows:

```
TypeError: Class extends value #<child> is not a constructor or null
at lib/websocket/events.js (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:10194:52)
at __require (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:4:50)
at lib/websocket/util.js (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:10436:40)
at __require (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:4:50)
at lib/websocket/websocket.js (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:10979:96)
at __require (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:4:50)
...
at Gaxios.validateOpts (/home/ubuntu/xxx/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:213:32)
```

The error seems to be related to the following code snippet:

```
const isFormData = typeof FormData === 'undefined'
                ? false
                : (opts === null || opts === void 0 ? void 0 : opts.data) instanceof FormData;
```

Interestingly,

1. the error disappears when all the references of `FormData` is removed.
2. the error only occurs for node version 18.18.2 and above except version 19.

This suggests a potential compatibility issue with the specific Node.js versions. Further investigation into the release notes indicates that [this](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/50153/files) commit might have introduced the problem.

I have a few questions regarding this issue:

1. How does the above error occur simply by referencing a token/variable using typeof?
2. Based on the findings, can we conclude that this is an issue introduced in the Node.js package starting from version [18.18.2](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/main/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V18.md#2023-10-13-version-18182-hydrogen-lts-rafaelgss)?
3. Does this imply that the libraries involved (googleapis, gaxios, undici) are not compatible with these Node.js versions?
4. What could be a possible solution for this, considering it appears to be a library-level issue?

Any insights or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!